# Compilador indica enum inexistente que existe

Tags: c#, namespace, mono, using, enums

Estou usando o compilador Mono. Quando tentei compilar isso:

```
using static System.Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo;
using static System.Globalization.UnicodeCategory;

namespace AS3Kit.Lexical
{
    static class Validator
    {
        static bool TestCategory(UnicodeCategory cat, int cp)
            { return CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(cp) == cat; }

        // ...
    }
}
```

Ocorreu o erro

> D:\hydroper\local\work\cs\AS3Kit>mcs -recurse:source/*.cs -out:AS3Kit.exe
>   source\Lexical\Validator.cs(8,28): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Uni
>   codeCategory' could not be found. Are you missing`System.Globalization' using d
>   irective?
>   Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings

O que está querendo dizer, o tipo `UnicodeCategory` não existe. Porém, se visitarmos o repositório do GitHub, podemos ver que o enum `System.Globalization.UnicodeCategory` (CLI do C#) foi implementado. Então por que o compilador não acha :v ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem problemas nos dois.

O primeiro está importando o tipo estaticamente e usado o nome do tipo para acessar os membros, ou faz uma coisa ou faz outra. Se deseja usar o nome do tipo não importe estaticamente. Tem mais problemas nesta parte do código.

O segundo é que está importando estaticamente a enumeração, mas não está usando nenhum membro dele. A importação estática é para acessar seus membros de forma direta. Se só vai usar o tipo e não os membros, que é o caso, então importe o tipo de forma normal, ou seja, pelo *namespace*, porque você quer o que está dentro dele, o tipo e não o que está dentro do tipo, não o faça estaticamente.

Se quer garrafas de refrigerante, peça um engradado or fardo de garrafas. Se quer o líquido que está na garrafa peça a garrafa. Quando conceituamos direito tudo funciona, o problema é que pensamos mecanicamente e muitas vezes não sabemos o que queremos de fato.

Assim:

```
using static System.Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo;
using System.Globalization;

static class Validator {
    static void Main() {}
    static bool TestCategory(UnicodeCategory cat, char cp) => GetUnicodeCategory(cp) == cat;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/kkXKuj). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3OsEkz). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Typing/EnumStatically.cs).

Comment: Então fiz muita coisa errada :o Esse `using static` é um pouco diferente do `import static` do Java...

Comment: @Hogenesis Eles têm o mesmo propósito. Os dois servem para acessar os membros estáticos diretamente, sem escrever o nome da classe deles antes.